# Tabel cell and string in the same line itext

Tags: java, itext

how can I create pdf with cell before some string in the same line? I try

```
 PdfPTable tab=new PdfPTable(1);
 tab.addCell("T");
 tab.setWidthPercentage(3);
 tab.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
 document.add(new Paragraph(String.format("Something",tab)));
 document.add(tab);
```

but it doesn't work right.

Comment: It seems you're looking for a feature known as a "generic tag event". Unfortunataly, the description of your requirement is too vague to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
PdfPTable tab=new PdfPTable(2);
tab.addCell("T");
tab.addCell("Something");
tab.setWidthPercentage(30);
```

**UPDATE**

```
 PdfPTable tab=new PdfPTable(2);
 PdfPTable tabLeft=new PdfPTable(1);
 tabLeft.addCell("T");
 tab.addCell(tabLeft);
 tab.addCell("Something");
```

Comment: But here text Something you put in cell. I want put text T in cell and after put Something behind tabel but in the same line.

Comment: You still don't understand. I want have effect like in that: |T| Something where |T| is table cell with char T and Something is string outside table and in the same line as |T|